# pandas_gbq() error "Expected bytes, got a 'list' object"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to load a dataframe into BigQuery using `pandas_gbq()`. It return the following error:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'list' object
```

This is how my df looks like using `df.info()`:

```
Column, Non-Null, Count, Dtype
0,  conversion_date, 366248, non-null, dbdate
1,  conversion_timestamp, 366248, non-null, datetime64[ns, UTC]
2,  journey_id, 366109, non-null, object
3,  path_channels, 366248, non-null, object
4,  path_timestamps, 366248, non-null, object
5,  conversion, 366248, non-null, boolean
6,  conversions_in_session, 366248, non-null, Int64
7,  conversion_value, 365595, non-null, float64
8,  attr_first_click, 366248, non-null, object
9,  attr_last_click, 366248, non-null, object
10, attr_last_non_direct_click, 366248, non-null, object
11, attr_position, 366248, non-null, object
12, attr_time_decay, 366248, non-null, object
13 attr_linear 366248 non-null object
14 attr_markov 366248 non-null object
dtypes: Int64(1), boolean(1), datetime64[ns, UTC](1), dbdate(1), float64(1), object(10)
```

Comment: Could you share the sample code that you're using to replicate this at my end?